# Freebsd 10.1 / Ruby on Rails / Apache 2.4 / Phusion Passenger : client denied by server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, freebsd

I can't get passenger to work with apache24 on freebsd 10.1

If I place the virtualhost below into my httpd.conf not only does a request for the virtualhost return 403 forbidden but also the server's hostname documentroot which is just `index.html` file without rails returns 403 forbidden also the `httpd-error.log` only says client denied by server configuration.

I assume passenger is failing to rewrite the requests from `/public to /app/views/index.html.erb` because I didn't put any html files in 
/public Already installed mod_fastcgi but responses are still 403 forbidden

This is the tail of my `httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.18/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache24/mod_fastcgi.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.18
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby21
</IfModule>

# Virtual hosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /usr/home/myusername/websites/myrailsappname/public
 <Directory /usr/home/myusername/websites/myrailsappname/public>
 AllowOverride all
 Options -MultiViews
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Include etc/apache24/Includes/*.conf
```

Comment: Replace deprecated directives `Order` and `Allow` by `Require all granted`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4 has different allow/deny rules:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

You will want to update your rule:

```
<Directory /usr/home/myusername/websites/myrailsappname/public>
AllowOverride all
Options -MultiViews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to something like:

```
<Directory /usr/home/myusername/websites/myrailsappname/public>
AllowOverride all
Options -MultiViews
require all granted
</Directory>
```